# In Scala, when would be a good time to use lazily evaluated parameter rather than to use a function as a parameter?

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, lazy-evaluation, callbyname, call-by-value

```
def getStr(): String = {
  println("getStr is running")
  "str"
}

def lazyHello(para: => String) = {
  println("lazy hello is runing")
  println(para)
}

def notLazyHello(para: String) = {
  println("not lazy hello is runing")
  println(para)
}

def anoyHello(para: () => String) = {
  println("anoy hello is runing")
  println(para())
}

notLazyHello(getStr)
lazyHello(getStr)
anoyHello(getStr)
```

got this result:

```
scala> notLazyHello(getStr)
getStr is running
not lazy hello is runing
str

scala>     lazyHello(getStr)
lazy hello is runing
getStr is running
str

scala>     anoyHello(getStr)
anoy hello is runing
getStr is running
str
```

seems like lazyHello and anoyHello perform the same.

So, in Scala, when would be a good time to use lazily evaluated parameter rather than to use a function as a parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observation is correct. `lazyHello` and `anoyHello` are in fact the same. This is because `para: => String` is shorthand for `para: () => String`.

Another way to look at this:

`() => String` is a function that takes no parameters and returns a string.

`=> String` is something that evaluates to a string, without taking parameters. So essentially call-by-name is a function without an input parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Basically there's no technical difference between lazy evaluated parameter and `Function0` parameter. There are pro's and cons of both the implementation.

`Function0` parameter is definitely verbose. So if you change them to lazy parameter, code will become much readable.

Here is a bug prone situation of lazy evaluation.

Consider following code

```
def inner = println("inner called")

def execute(f: => Unit) = {
  println("executing")
  f
}

def redirect(f: => Unit) = {
  println("redirecting")
  execute(f)
}

redirect(inner) // will print - 
                // redirecting
                // executing
                // inner called
```

Now think for some reason you forget to put `=>` in the execute function. Code will compile correctly, but the behavior will be different and might introduce bugs.

```
def execute(f: Unit) = {
  println("executing")
  f
} 

def redirect(f: => Unit) = {
  println("redirecting")
  execute(f)
}

redirect(inner) // will print - 
                // redirecting
                // inner called
                // executing
```

But if you use `Function0`, the code will not compile. So, the `Function0` parameters are less bug prone.

```
def inner() = println("inner called")

def execute(f:() => Unit) = {
  println("executing")
  f()
}

def redirect(f:() => Unit) = {
  println("redirecting")
  execute(f)
}

redirect(inner) // will print - 
                // redirecting
                // executing
                // inner called
```

=========================================

```
def inner() = println("inner called")

def execute(f:Unit) = {
  println("executing")
  f
}

def redirect(f:() => Unit) = {
  println("redirecting")
  execute(f)               // Will not compile.
}
```

Furthermore, You can clearly see when that value is evaluated.

Anyway if you are so sure what you do, you can use any one of them. Decision is yous.